# Postgres Nested JSONB Query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB column, data, in the orders table:

```
# orders.data

{
  discount_codes: [
    { code: 'foo' },
    { code: 'bar'}
  ]
}

# codes_array: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

I'm trying to select "orders where discount_codes contain a code in codes_array". I could not figure out how to write this query exactly. I read about the [*] operator but am unsure how to use it in this context.

This only searches the first element of discount_codes:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS
WHERE data->'discount_codes'->0->'code' ?| array['foo','bar','baz']
```

This only searches for 'foo'.

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS
WHERE data @@ '$.discount_codes[*].code == "foo"'
```

I've been reading the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH but I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract all codes into an array, then apply the `?|` operator on that array:

```
select *
from orders
where jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.discount_codes[*].code') ?| array['foo','bar','baz']
```

The expression `jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.discount_codes[*].code')` returns `["foo", "bar"]` for your sample JSON